# Sum of two lines through zero in $\mathbb R^{2}$ is $\mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L_{1}$ anc $L_{2}$ be distinct lines through 0 in $\mathbb R^{2}$. Use a geometric argument to verify that $L_{1}$ + $L_{2}$ = $\mathbb R^{2}$ as subspaces. I am completely confused by this question, I am not really sure how to show this works and also I am unsure what it means when it says "use a geometric argument". Could someone help me please?

Thanks!
Helen

Comment: What is your definition of summation on lines? Is it the span of their direction vectors?

Comment: The geometric argument probably involves a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the sum of 2 lines means, you take a multiple of the directional vector out of 1 and another multiple of the directional vector of the other;
In your example, you take C*V where C is an arbitrary constant, and V is a vector along L1, and D*W where D is an arbitrary constant, and W is a vector along L2.
If L1 and L2 are distinct, V and W are linearly independent; so they span the entire euclidean plane.

About the geometric argument, draw 2 arbitrary lines, and look at what points in the plane you can construct by taking a point on one line, and one on the other and summing/subtracting them?

Hope it helped!